# Write Null in Database if the TextBoxes are Empty

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, dbnull

All I want to do is to insert Null with the database when the textbox is empty.

```
 --ACCOUNT

 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT account ON


  INSERT INTO dbo.account
      ( 
        AccntID                   ,
        managedby                 ,
        AccountHolder             ,
        Description               ,
        AccountType               ,
        ContactPerson             ,
        ContactNumber             ,
        EmailAddress              ,
        Address                   ,
        ClientTYpe                ,
        SchemeType                ,
        SalesManager              ,
        DateCreated               ,
        Login                     ,
        Password                  ,
        Balance                   ,
        FilterOption              ,
        Enable22                  ,
        AllowExtendedConfig                  
      ) 
-- Insert statements for procedure here

 VALUES (@AccntID, @managedby, @AccountHolder, @Description, @AccountType, @ContactPerson, @ContactNumber, @EmailAddress, @Address, @ClientType, @SchemeType, @SalesManager, @DateCreated, @Login, @Password, @Balance, @FilterOption, @Enable22, @AllowExtendedConfig)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT account OFF



END
```

What is the best way to add NULL values to the database when my textboxes are empty

Comment: What are you using, ADO.NET, Entity framework, Linq-To-Sql, etc?? Can you show the code where aou're trying to insert the record?

Comment: vb.net,t-sl 


 INSERT INTO dbo.account
          ( 
            AccntID ,managedby,accountholder,)

Comment: Provide scema of `dbo.account` table, mention `Nullable` fields. Also, provide to which columns you need to set DB Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up helper functions such as:

```
Public Function DbNullOrStringValue(ByVal value As String) As Object
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        Return value
    End If
End Function
```

And so the first code block would be simplified by calling it thus:

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccntID", DbNullOrStringValue(TextBox1.Text)) 
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managedby", DbNullOrStringValue(TextBox2.Text)) 
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountHolder", DbNullOrStringValue(TextBox3.Text)) 
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DbNullOrStringValue(TextBox4.Text)) 
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", DbNullOrStringValue(TextBox5.Text))
```

`Cmd` is your `SqlCommanad` object

Comment: this is my parameter looks like..how can i connect my code with your code..
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccntID", TextBox1.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@managedby", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountHolder", TextBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", TextBox4.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", TextBox5.Text)

Comment: this errors appear when i execute this code of yours.
Overload resolution failed because no Public Add can be called with these arguments:
     'Public Function Add(text As String )As
System.Windows.Forms.Listviewitem.Listview.Subitems)As
System.Windows.Forms.Listviewitem.Listview.Subitem':
      Argument matching parameter item cannot convert from DBNull to ListViewSubitems

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel - This is a different issue. Your DataSet/DataTable has DBNull values. Please check if your Database call is returning any DBNull values. I believe your this problem has resolved and you are now dealing with other promblem now. Add a new post with this issue under Winforms and ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Consider something lighter than a new method :

```
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccntID", IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text),  DBNull.Value, TextBox1.Text))
```

But for the rest, use a `SqlDataAdapter` as suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to inherited text box and add additional functionality to it

```
Public Class MyText
    Inherits TextBox

    'Either change default text property (but this will bug you while comparing text property)
    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            MyBase.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Best way will be to write new property to use in sql query
    Public ReadOnly Property TextSQL() As String
        Get
            If Me.Text = String.Empty Then
                Return "NULL"
            Else
                Return Me.Text
                'Return "'" & Me.Text & "'" 'or this
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

now use this text box in your application

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountholder", txt_accHolder.TextSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure you can use following:

Assumption: parameter name is @TextData

```
 NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@TextData)),'')
```

It will return NULL if @TextData = ''.